# TabControl ItemTemplate with UserControl inside

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a question about using TabControl with mvvm pattern.
Here is some parts of my code:

```
<UserControl>
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <vm:TabsViewModel />
        </UserControl.DataContext>
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary >
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Converters.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>        
        </UserControl.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Customer.LastName}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
                </Style>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContentTemplate" x:Shared="false">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <GroupBox Header="Info">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customer.FullName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </GroupBox>

                        <GroupBox Header="Finances" Grid.Column="1" >
                            <controls:CustomerFinancesView DataContextChanged="CustomerFinancesView_DataContextChanged">
<controls:CustomerFinancesView.DataContext>
<vm:FinancesViewModel />
</controls:CustomerFinancesView.DataContext>
                            </controls:CustomerFinancesView>
                        </GroupBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <TabControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTab, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemContentTemplate}"/>  
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Underlaying view model provide methods and commands to add or remove tabs. Like so:

```
public class TabsViewModel : InteractableModel
{
    ObservableCollection<TabModel> _tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<TabModel> Tabs
    {
        get 
        {
            return _tabs;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (_tabs == value)
                return;

            _tabs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Tabs");
        }
    }

    private TabModel _currentTab;
    public TabModel CurrentTab
    {
        get { return _currentTab; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentTab == value)
                return;

            _currentTab = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTab");
        }
    }

    public TabsViewModel()
    {
        ...
    }


    void OpenTab(Customer customer)
    {
      var existedTab = Tabs.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Customer.ID == customer.ID);
      if (existedTab != null)
      {
        existedTab.Refresh();
        CurrentTab = existedTab;
      }
      else
      {
    var newTab = new TabModel(customer);

    Tabs.Add(newTab);

    CurrentTab = newTab;
      }
    }

    void RemoveTab(object param)
    {
       var tabToRemove = Tabs.ElementAtOrDefault((int)param);

       if (tabToRemove != null)
       {
          Tabs.Remove(tabToRemove);
       }
    }

}
```

}

As you can see, content of each TabItem templated by TabItemContentTemplate DataTemplate. This DataTemplate contains UserControl inside. Assume that this is just empty usercontrol from VS template.
When i'm open first tab - this control ctor is called, corresponding viewmodel creates, and DataContextChanged event is raised. But opening any other tab, or reopening this one doesn't affect on creating this UserControl - it's still those control instance that was created for the first tab opening. Same thing with viewmodel (ctor not called) and event (not raising).
Please help me to find out a way to instantiate this user control from datatemplate every time i'm open tab (OR every time i'm open NEW tab; both variants suits) and destroy it every time i'm closing tab. I've read a lot articles about this, but only thing i found is to use

```
x:Shared=false
```

on DataTemplate. But this workaround isn't working for me.

P.S. My final goal is to provide Tab-specific data to DataTemplate's inner UserControl using mvvm pattern. (every tab stores a lot information inside. This information is separated into usercontrols with it's own view model. I want to customize displaying data for each tab controls by binding it to current tab model. Like so: TabsViewModel stores Collection; TabModel stores Model, Control1VM(Model), Control2VM(Model), ...)

Comment: Load all user controls when it loads for the first time. Tab control constructor will call once. if you need to initialize when on tab change then attach a command to tab change event will allow you to create instance of VM on tab change.

Comment: I think you should elaborate on why you want multiple UserControls.  Generally when using a TabControl with MVVM it's fine for multiple ViewModels to share a single View because the underlying DataContext (and therefore any associated bindings) are updated automatically when the user changes tabs.  The user can't tell the difference.

Comment: @RogerN thanks for your comment. I want to use multiple UserControls to simplify xaml code. I'm suppose that single tab view will have too much data inside (and code for displaying that data), so i've decided to separate this. Another reason is a capability of reusing those controls.

Comment: @Abin Mathew thanks for your comment. Your idea may solve a problem in some situation. But in my context - loading all viewmodels isn't a good idea because it will slow down app. Best will be if user control re-instantiate itself (and it's own viewmodel which i'm bind as datacontext staticly).